# Finding max number in an arbitrarily-lengthened set isn't working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have this code wherein I'm trying to get the largest number out of the arguments that are passed. For some reason it doesn't work and I'm not exactly sure why. The code works when I input 2 numbers but when 3 or more are passed I get these errors:

> <sub>prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
>   prog.cpp:31:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘max(int, int, int)’
>
>   prog.cpp:31:29: note: candidate is:
>
>   prog.cpp:24:30: note: template constexpr decltype (handle::helper::max(max::args ...)) max(Args ...)
>
>   prog.cpp:24:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
>   prog.cpp: In substitution of ‘template constexpr decltype (handle::helper::max(args ...)) max(Args ...) [with Args = {int, int, int}]’:
>
>   prog.cpp:31:29:   required from here
>
>   prog.cpp:24:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘handle::helper::max(int&, int&, int&)’
>
>   prog.cpp:24:30: note: candidates are:
>   prog.cpp:11:18: note: static T handle::helper::max(T, T) [with T = int; Args = {int, int}]
>
>   prog.cpp:11:18: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
>
>   prog.cpp:16:18: note: static T handle::helper::max(T, T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, int}]
>
>   prog.cpp:16:18: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided</sub>

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace handle
{
    template <typename... Args>
    struct helper {};

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    struct helper<T, Args...>
    {
        static T constexpr max(T x, T y)
        {
            return x > y ? x : y;
        }

        static T constexpr max(T x, T y, Args... args)
        {
            return max(x, max(y, args...));
        }
    };
}

template <typename... Args>
static auto constexpr max(Args... args) -> decltype(handle::helper<Args...>::max(args...))
{
    return handle::helper<Args...>::max(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << max(5, 3, 7); // fails
}
```

I'm really confused because I thought I had this down. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks.

---

**Update:** Thanks Named. Since this question is now resolved, here is the result:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace handle
{
    template <typename T, typename V>
    static auto constexpr max(T const& x, V const& y)
    -> typename std::common_type<T, V>::type
    {
        return x > y ? x : y;
    }

    template <typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
    static auto constexpr max(T const& x, V const& y, Args const&... args)
    -> typename std::common_type<T, typename std::common_type<V, Args...>::type>::type
    {
        return max(x, max(y, args...));
    }
}

template <typename... Args>
static auto constexpr max(Args const&... args) -> decltype(handle::max<Args...>(args...))
{
    return handle::max<Args...>(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << max(5, 3, 7.8, 2, 4, 55); // 55
}
```

Thank you everybody!

Comment: Why is your function in a struct, that only serves to make things more confusing, I believe the function should be templated not the struct

Comment: Why not use `std::max(std::initializer_list<T>)`?

Comment: @aaronman I can't partially specialize functions, so I need to use a class template.

Comment: what do you mean by you can't partially specialize functions, also since everything is the same type in yours there is really no need for variadic templates

Comment: @KennyTM why not std::set, why not some lib, etc?Op is interested in THIS

Comment: prog.cpp:16:18: note: static T handle::helper::max(T, T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, int}]
prog.cpp:16:18: note: candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided  This is the reason, provide max(T,T,Args)

Comment: Just a note: `constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: @Morwenn Right, forgot about that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem has been pointed out by Morwenn. 
However you can still simplify your code to just this. (You can indeed specialize function templates in C++11)

```
namespace handle
{

    template <typename T, typename V>
    static auto max(const T& x, const V& y)  
    -> typename std::common_type<T,V>::type
    {
        return x > y ? x : y;
    }

    template <typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
    static auto max(const T& x, const V& y, const Args&... args) 
    -> decltype( max(x, max(y, args...)) )
    {
        return max(x, max(y, args...));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << handle::max(1,2,3.3); 
}
```

This has the advantage of returning the proper type when you compare different types.

---

EDIT: Aparrently this will not work when you have more than 3 args. The problem seems to be that `gcc` doesn't consider the variadic `max` itself when evaluating

```
decltype(max(y, args...)
```

You can compromise and use this instead

```
template <typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
static auto max(const T& x, const V& y, const Args&... args) 
 -> typename std::common_type<T, V>::type
{
    return max(x, max(y, args...));
}
```

---

A better approach suggested by 0x499602D2 in the comments

```
template <typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
static auto max(const T& x, const V& y, const Args&... args)
-> typename std::common_type<T, V, Args...>::type
{
    return max(x, max(y, args...));
}
```

---

---

**EDIT**: With `gcc`'s `-std=c++1y` flag (which allows you to emit the trailing return types) you can do this like. (*the case above is definitely a bug then*)

```
template <typename T, typename V>
auto max(const T& x, const V& y) {
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

template <typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
auto max(const T& x, const V& y, const Args&... args) {
    return max(x, max(y, args...));
}
```

Comment: Your code will work perfectly if you replace `typename std::common_type<T, decltype(max(y, args...)) >::type` with `typename std::common_type<T, typename std::common_type<V, Args...>::type>::type`

Comment: @0x499602D2 That is actually better. I think the issue is with gcc. I will edit to your suggestion.

Comment: @soon See the edits. This should work I think. And with the proper type selection.

Comment: Well, that's actually a strange error. I thought of using `std::common_type` too, but never thought it would resolve the problem :o

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that the arguments are wrong.  You are calling `helper<int,int,int>::max`.  In your template:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct helper<T, Args...>
{
    constexpr static T max(T x, T y)
    {
        return x > y ? x : y;
    }

    constexpr static T max(T x, T y, Args... args)
    {
        return max(x, max(y, args...));
    }
};
```

`Args` becomes `int,int`, so you end up with a `max` function that takes two parameters, and a `max` function that takes four parameters, but none that take three parameters.

However, it isn't as simple as just removing one of the arguments:

```
    constexpr static T max(T x, Args... args)
    {
        return max(x, max(args...));
    }
```

because now your function becomes ambiguous with `max(x,y)`.

What you could do instead is provide specializations like these:

```
template <typename T>
struct helper<T> {
  static T max(T x) { return x; }
};

template <typename X,typename Y,typename... Args>
struct helper<X,Y,Args...> {
  constexpr static X max(X x,Y y,Args... args)
  {
    return std::max(x,helper<Y,Args...>::max(y,args...));
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you using `std::max` here?

Comment: @templateboy: seemed simpler than making another function to do the same thing, but you could certainly write your own max function and use that instead.  Just make sure to give it a different name so that you don't run into name hiding issues.